# NativeScript installation

Tags: java, nativescript

After installing NativeScript Im getting this error when trying to run the following command
**ns doctor**

````
C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-11.0.17.8-hotspot\bin;
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;
C:\Program Files\Python310\Scripts\;
C:\Program Files\Python310\;
C:\WINDOWS\system32;
C:\WINDOWS;
C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\;
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19\bin;
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\WINDOWS\system32>ns doctor
√ Getting environment information

TIP: To avoid setting up the necessary environment variables, you can use the chocolatey package manager to install the Android SDK and its dependencies.

There seem to be issues with your configuration.
√ Getting NativeScript components versions information...
√ Component nativescript has 8.4.0 version and is up to date.
√ Your ANDROID_HOME environment variable is set and points to correct directory.
√ Your adb from the Android SDK is correctly installed.
√ The Android SDK is installed.
√ A compatible Android SDK for compilation is found.
√ Local builds for iOS can be executed only on a macOS system. To build for iOS on a different operating system, you can use the NativeScript cloud infrastructure.
× Error executing command 'javac'. Make sure you have installed The Java Development Kit (JDK) and set JAVA_HOME environment variable.
 You will not be able to build your projects for Android.
To be able to build for Android, verify that you have installed The Java Development Kit (JDK) and configured it according to system requirements as
 described in https://docs.nativescript.org/environment-setup.html

× WARNING: The Java Development Kit (JDK) is not installed or is not configured properly.
 You will not be able to work with the Android SDK and you might not be able
to perform some Android-related operations. To ensure that you can develop and
test your apps for Android, verify that you have installed the JDK as
described in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/install_overview.html (for JDK 8).

Your environment is not configured properly and you will not be able to execute local builds.
Verify that your environment is configured according to the system requirements described at
https://docs.nativescript.org/environment-setup.html.
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools;
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.5\bin;
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;
C:\Program Files\nodejs\;
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;
C:\Program Files (x86)\BrowserStackLocal\;
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.3\bin;
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\5.0\bin;
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\mongosh\;
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.2.3\bin;
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm

Also when I checked my Environment variables I can see this

```
C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-11.0.17.8-hotspot\bin;
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;
C:\Program Files\Python310\Scripts\;
C:\Program Files\Python310\;
C:\WINDOWS\system32;
C:\WINDOWS;
C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\;
**C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19\bin;**
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools;
**C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.5\bin;**
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;
C:\Program Files\nodejs\;
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;
C:\Program Files (x86)\BrowserStackLocal\;
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.3\bin;
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\5.0\bin;
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\mongosh\;
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.2.3\bin;
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm
````

Is the multiple jdks causing the issue, please guide me

Thanks in advance :)

I tried looking into the documentation marked as red in the command line error and also on google but nowhere it talks about multiple version issue

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Instead [edit] your question to include the commands/output as (properly formatted) text instead.

Comment: can you run javac in the terminal, as well as javac -version?

Comment: Yes, after running javac I get a list of options for usage and javac -version outputs javac 11.0.17